# CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 6.0'

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, core-plot

I have dowloaded a project name called Plot_Gallery _ios which is mainly runs for plotting of graph.This was downloaded from core_plot,the main target project is Plot_Gallery_IOS and also it has sub project file called CorePlot-CocoaTouch.xcodeProj whic contain all library files which is mainly used of running of this project.

Problem what i am facing is when i try to load this app in my ipad after compiling it gives one error i.e

**CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 6.0'**

Iam tryin to fix this problem from long time i am not able to..i tried going to build settings and changing **code signing identity** to **Dont code sign** and also by selecting **debug** as **Ios SDK** i am tryign all possible ways to fix it but i am not able to load this app into my ipad.

i also tried selecting Ios SDK as **iphoneDeveloper** but i get **linker errors** so wats the issue??Is it bcoz it contains 2 target project where Plot_Gallery_IOS is main and in sub  there is CorePot_cocoatouch.xcodeProject and rest all other files..

So can anyone plz tel me  how to solve this issue.i am stuck up with this issue from long time.

Answer (score 27):

Hey I manage to fix it changing the codesigning values in the build settings. I attach an image so you can see it:

[image: Solution]

I hope that will help you! Let me know!

Answer (score 12):

1. Go to this folder: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk` .
2. You need to copy this file: `SDKSettings.plist` and paste it in your desktop.
3. Open the file you just copied with Xcode. In `DefaultProperties` you'll find the following string: `CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED`.
4. You need to change it's value from 'YES' to 'NO'.
5. Save it, move it back to the original folder (replace it with the original file) and there you go.

Comment: Are you sure you've done all the steps correctly? the point is to change your current sdks' setting from the default- code signing is required to code singing is NOT required.

Comment: where do you get that

Answer (score 1):

[image]

For Xcode5, Maybe Provisioning Profile section you choose the wrong item of "Any iOS SDK", just change to your own profile instead of your download one.

Answer (score 0):

To solve then problem,  You must register Don´t Code Sign, compile your code, and then place the corresponding profile.

Please see the **Assigning Provisioning Profiles to Build Configurations** section from this page on Apple's developer site:

https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/technotes/tn2250/_index.html

Comment: That link is now flagged as a retired document…

Answer (score 0):

To release/adhoc the app the solution in my case was to set to do not sign all the Code Signing Identity fields, and do the same for the provisionings profiles.

After that i set the Release->Any iOS SDK  to the right provisioning profile, Xcode automatically set the Code Signing Identity-> Any iOS SDK to the proper Identity and i do the normal Archive-> publish procedure.