# How to completely clean / reset iOS provisioning profiles and certificates in Xcode safely?

Tags: xcode, certificate, keychain, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to get my provisioning profile to work. I think there may be some UI changes between Xcode 4 and Xcode 5 that are confusing me. Nevertheless, I'd like to clean out my provisioning profiles and certificates as much as possible from Xcode and Keychain Access so that I can start fresh, so hopefully then I will be less confused about which thing does what.

**QUESTION: Any recommendations for good, exhaustive code signing tutorials for Xcode? Hopefully with visuals and/or updated for Xcode 5?**

Since that is a vague question, here are some possibly better questions:

- Are there any Xcode-related keys or certificates in Keychain Access that are ***not*** safe to delete? I.s., keys / certificates that are a pain to restore (rather than just re-downloading them from the Apple Developer site)?
- Should I delete certificates whose status is "This root certificate is not trusted"? It has the red X next to it.

I'm actually trying to get push notifications working via Parse, but in the process of setting that up I think I broke everything: https://parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications

I wish I knew what question to ask but I'm kindof just gaping at my computer screen like a moron...
http://youtu.be/nRKHkLuZ0ZU

Answer (score 0):

Hello: I managed to get my own setup working again without fully answering my own question above :-/ so here are some insights / current ideas / remaining questions:

- **DON'T DELETE PRIVATE KEYS**: Although I understand *how* private keys are generated (i.e., mathematically from the public key), I'm still not exactly sure *where* the private keys are generated. Right now it *seems* like they are included when you download certificates from the Apple Developer Center website ("Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles"). The key here is that, in my quest to "delete" old certificates from Keychain Access, I was unwittingly also deleting the associated private key. I haven't been able to find a way to delete old and duplicate certificates without deleting the associated private key. My current solution, then, is **don't delete old certificates, even if they are cluttering**.
- Another thing is that **in Xcode 5 it seems like you have to select explicitly which provisioning profile you want to use**. This field ("Provisioning Profile") is still under "Code Signing" under your project's "Build Settings." My memory tells me that this used to just be part of the drop-down when you selected your desired "Code Signing Identity"...but I have a bad memory. However, the screenshot in the following Stack Overflow answer suggests my memory might not be off: [CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 6.0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13582401/codesign-error-code-signing-is-required-for-product-type-application-in-sdk)
- **BACKUP YOUR (working) DEVELOPER PROFILE VIA XCODE**. Here are instructions. I was lucky that I have another machine with working credentials so I could just export my developer profile from that machine and into my non-working machine: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-accounts_preferences/articles/export_signing_assets.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013306-CH8-SW1

Please leave comments letting me know what other information I can provide in order to make this a real answer...and maybe then I can create a good visual tutorial for others to use :-)