# CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 7.0

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode5, ipa

I have one project of my client, i am able to create IPA and able to install certificate all of other app but not for this let me paste here error i am getting i have also tried some of googled results and also some others as well

**I checked following links**
[iOS 7.0 No code signing identities found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19197497/ios-7-0-no-codesigning-identities-found)
[CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 6.0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13582401/codesign-error-code-signing-is-required-for-product-type-application-in-sdk)

**Error i am Getting**

> Check dependencies
>
> Code Sign error: No codesigning identities found: No codesigning
>   identities (i.e. certificate and private key pairs) that match the
>   provisioning profile specified in your build settings (“projectname”)
>   were found. CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type
>   'Application' in SDK 'iOS 7.0'
>
> No codesigning identities found: No codesigning identities (i.e.
>   certificate and private key pairs) that match the provisioning profile
>   specified in your build settings (“projectname”) were found.
>
> CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type
>   'Application' in SDK 'iOS 7.0'

Please help me ... thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You need to have the proper certificate and mobile provisioning in Xcode to allow you to build something that runs on the device.  I'm assuming that you belong to the Apple iOS developer's program and you paid the $99/ year for it.  If not, do so.  When that is done, log into your developer account and select "Certificates, Identifiers and Profiles" on the right hand side of your home page, and follow all the directions under there PRECISELY.

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution which works for me:

1. Search "code sign" in Build settings
2. Change everything in code signing identity to "iOS developer", which are "Don't code sign" originally.

Bravo!

Comment: Thank you, you just taught me that build settings search is a thing, and made my life so much easier from this moment on. And it fixed my problem. Bravo indeed.